# Cannot compare 2 addresses in solidity code

Tags: solidity, truffle, addresses

Why do the results differ in the following:

```
truffle(development)> l.ownerOf(t) == l.ownerOf(t)
false
truffle(development)> l.ownerOf(t) != l.ownerOf(t)
true
```

Another version:

```
truffle(development)> var l1 = l.ownerOf(t)
undefined
truffle(development)> l1
'0xf17f52151ebef6c7334fad080c5704d77216b732'
truffle(development)> l1==l1
true
truffle(development)> var l2 = l.ownerOf(t)
undefined
truffle(development)> l1==l2
false
truffle(development)> l2
'0xf17f52151ebef6c7334fad080c5704d77216b732'
```

I can't seem to compare two identical addresses from a view function with the same parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this has to do with the the fact that both l1 and l2 are actually promises, though they log their results. This logic works:

```
truffle(development)> l.ownerOf(t).then(function(i){lll = i})
undefined
truffle(development)> l.ownerOf(t).then(function(i){ll = i})
undefined
truffle(development)> ll==lll
true
```